# google drive preview generation while uploading document

Tags: google-drive-api

Can a google drive application generate a preview for a file (which is not handled by google drive by default) when a file of that type is uploaded by the user, rather than creating it using that application?(Assuming the user has authorized that application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, sorry.

The closest we have is being able to generate a third party thumbnail for a file. Your app can decide how the file will appear in the Google Drive thumbnail view by uploading the necessary image(s).

The video here explains it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG5-9zlaPL8